# Why do I get a "no matching function" error when I open an fstream with the file name in a std::string?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that reads in a list of strings from a file and checks what strings are missing from a second file and prints them to the screen. However, I am currently getting an error when I try to compile. Below is the error I am getting when I try to compile as well as the code. Thank you for the help

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

ifstream IN_FILE;
ofstream OUT_FILE;

int main()  { 
    int k = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    string a[5000];
    string b[5000];
    string filename;
    bool good;

    //open file and check if valid entry
    cout << "\n\nWhat is the name of the first file (ex: filename.txt)\n" << endl << "FILENAME: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    IN_FILE.open(filename);
    while(!IN_FILE) {
        cout << "Sorry the file you entered could not be opened\n";
        cout << "\n\nWhat is the name of the first file (ex: filename.txt)\n" << endl << "FILENAME: ";
        getline(cin, filename);
        IN_FILE.open(filename);
    }

    //Read every line from file
    while(!IN_FILE.eof()) {
        getline(IN_FILE, a[k]);
        k++;
    }
    n = k;
    k = 0;
    IN_FILE.close();

    //open file and check if valid entry
    cout << "\n\nWhat is the name of the first file (ex: filename.txt)\n" << endl << "FILENAME: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    IN_FILE.open(filename);
    while(!IN_FILE) {
        cout << "Sorry the file you entered could not be opened\n";
        cout << "\n\nWhat is the name of the first file (ex: filename.txt)\n" << endl << "FILENAME: ";
        getline(cin, filename);
        IN_FILE.open(filename);
    }

    //Read every line from file
    while(!IN_FILE.eof()) {
        getline(IN_FILE, b[k]);
        k++;
    }
    m = k;
    k = 0;
    
    //Compare the arrays and print all elements is array a that are not in array b
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  { 
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            if (a[i] == b[j]) 
                break; 
  
        if (j == m) 
            cout << a[i] << endl; 
    } 
    
    return 0; 
}
```

This is the error:

```
checkTester.cpp:25:26: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&)'
     IN_FILE.open(filename);
```

Comment: As to the problem you're trying to solve, note that you may get stack overflow issues due to declaring those large `string` arrays.  Prefer to use `std::vector<std::string>`.  Also, if you `std::sort`-ed those two arrays after reading in the values, and then called `std::set_difference`, the amount of code would be reduced down to around 5 or 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This construct works for standard C++ 11 and newer compilers:

```
std::string filename;
//...
IN_FILE.open(filename);
```

This is basically the code you have now.  However, the above will *not* work with pre-standard C++ 11 compilers (C++ 98, 03).

If you are compiling using a pre-standard C++ 11 compiler, then the code above should be:

```
std::string filename;
//...
IN_FILE.open(filename.c_str()); // Note the null-terminated const char *
```

Basically, the `std::string` version of `open` did not exist before C++ 11.  Before C++ 11, you had to specify the name using a C-style, null-terminated string.

Thus the error you are seeing is because you are compiling in a version of C++ before C++ 11.